# Multiple-inherited derived class: How to reuse derived functions without repeating calls to base

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to complete some school homework, and I've just noticed there might be a problem caused by reusing a function from a base class in a multiply inherited derived class.

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class A
class B: public A
class C: public A

class D: public B, public C
```

Each class has this method:

```
virtual void read(ifstream& in);
```

In `class B` and in `class C`, the `read()` function is also calling `class A::read()`:

```
void B::read(ifstream& in)
{
    A::read(in);
    /* read method of B*/
}

void C::read(ifstream& in)
{
    A::read(in);
    /* read method of C*/
}
```

Now, the problem is, that when I want to make a `read()` function for `class D`, I'm actually calling `A::read()` twice:

```
void D::read(ifstream& in)
{
    B::read(in);
    C::read(in);
    /* read method of D*/
}
```

I know I can use the option of using the `A::read()` only in one class (`B` or `C`), but let's say I need to use it in both classes.

Comment: It would probably help to know what `read()` actually does in each implementation.

Comment: This is not really specific to inheritance. The same thing would happen if you had standalone (non-member) functions A_read, B_read and C_read. Also nothe that in your design you probably **want** to call `A::read` twice, because you inherit two separate copies of A.

Comment: @n.m. Good point, although I think most instances of this question arise in the context of inheritance. I imagine the OP is thinking of these classes as purely interfaces, with no data members, in which case (I think?) it's immaterial whether or not virtual inheritance is used. I mentioned this in my answer but maybe wasn't clear enough?

Comment: @underscore_d what a `read(istream&)` method would do in a pure interface?

Comment: @n.m. sorry, bad wording: I should've said "purely functional", i.e. without data members, not interfaces in the pure virtual/abstract sense. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think virtual inheritance makes any difference to such classes. But if the OP were to add members, virtual inheritance would seem to be required, based on what they've said about how they want the classes to work.

Comment: @underscore_d Yeah, got it. What `read(istream&)` method would do in a class with no data members? What would it read exactly?

Comment: @n.m. The input file that's passed as the parameter, of course? You can ask the OP what they would do with the read data, whether they want data members, or for any further details, not me.

Comment: @underscore_d yeah, read a file What would it do with the data read from that file? Throw it away? My rather educated guess is it would somehow assign that data to its data members. And the child class will read more data and assign to *its* data members. That's how the whole design looks to me. Unless OP chimes in with an alternate explanation, I don't really see this being used in any other way. It just makes zero sense in a class with no data members.

Comment: Or it might process in memory and write back out to another file. Look. I don't care. **@Ofir**: Use `virtual` inheritance to keep n.m. happy _in case_ you plan to read into data members.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of why multiple inheritance, especially from a common ancestor, is discouraged. Not because it's always bad - though it often is!- but more because it's usually *difficult*. If you can find an alternative, that's often preferable. Not necessarily. I'm sure you'll ponder this and decide if it's the best design. But for now, we're here to look at ways to avoid repeating `A::read()` and other pitfalls.

I start with an analogy to the famous Dreaded Diamond of Doom - not anywhere near as dread-worthy as legend suggests, but worth bearing in mind. It's illustrative that when working around the 'duplicated base members' problem created by such a diamond-shape inheritance hierarchy, by using **virtual inheritance** - the derived class now becomes fully responsible for calling all constructors of all of its virtual bases. Constructor calls don't chain upwards like normal, and data member initialisation is weird. Google it!

**N.B. You should use virtual inheritance if the top class of your diamond-shaped hierarchy has any data members, to avoid duplicating/introducing ambiguity for them, too. That's what it's for.** But back to the main topic where I use it as an analogy to functions (which don't strictly require it).

The idea is to take inspiration from virtual inheritance's requirement for the final class to manually call virtual bases' constructors, by handling derived classes' `read()` behaviours the same way: Avoid repeated calls by making each of your derived classes' public-facing `read()` methods fully responsible for calling all base ones. This also gives you fine control over not only which of the bases' methods are called - but also of their order.

How? We can factor out the real work of each derived `read()` to protected '`impl`ementation' functions in each class, and provide public overridden 'wrapper functions' in each *final* class. The wrapper functions will then be responsible for calling their respective class's `impl` and that of any required bases, in whichever order you want:

```
class A {
protected:
    void read_impl(ifstream &in) { /* A-specific stuff */ }
public:
    virtual void read(ifstream &in)
    {
        read_impl(in);
    }
};

class B: public A { // N.B. virtual public if A has data members!
protected:
    void read_impl(ifstream &in) { /*  B-specific stuff */ }
public:
    virtual void read(ifstream &in)
    {
        A::read_impl(in);
        read_impl(in); // B
    }
};

class C: public A {
protected:
    void read_impl(ifstream &in) { /* C-specific stuff */ }
public:
    virtual void read(ifstream &in)
    {
        A::read_impl(in);
        read_impl(in); // CMy
    }
};

class D: public B, public C {
protected:
    void read_impl(ifstream &in) { /* D-specific stuff */ }
public:
    virtual void read(ifstream &in)
    {
        A::read_impl(in);
        B::read_impl(in); // avoids calling A again from B
        C::read_impl(in); // ditto from C
        read_impl(in);    // D
    }
};
```

With this, you gain complete control over what base stuff each final class dones, and when, without unwanted repeated calls. In terms of DRY, `impl` functions mean no repetition of behavioural code is done for intermediate classes: the writing in each derived `read()` is all useful declarative information about how they orchestrate bases' behaviours. You can also add extra stuff between, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A very non-generic way to fix this issue is with booleans, just a switch for each class (B && C) to state if I should call my super class's function.
Another way to fix it is just not to call A's function in B or C.

Comment: Thank you, Can you explain the "non-generic" way more clearly please? As I mentioned, i need to use the read function with the option of calling A in B and in C (for other use), so basically I must call A's func in every class.

Comment: Inside the D class, You can call the A class and yields it's results onto B and C, and just call B&&C's virtual functions with the result of A. This way, you just need to set a boolean inside B&&C that turns off the option to use A's read function, and you basically used the read function in A for both B and C without reading twice.

Comment: I see. Sounds like I would have to use the option of not calling A's read function from B or C. thank you